# Python not accepting function variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

Whenever I run the code, python comes up with the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ""/Users/jim/Desktop/Python/TextWindow.py", line 7, in module
Read(name)

NameError: name 'name' is not defined

```
def Writeline(string):
    print(string)

def Read(name):
    name = input()

Read(name)

Writeline(name)
```

Comment: `name` is defined inside `Read` function and`name` has no meaning outside function

Comment: You haven't defined 'name' anywhere in your code other than inside a function. I think what you want is to remove name from being an argument to Read.

so:

def Read():

and then assign a variable to your call, so instead of Read(name), it would be:

name = Read()

Comment: [You may want to read up on Python functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), particularly variable scope :)

Comment: I am voting to close based on Erica's comment.

Comment: @Zetys 3.x according to tag.

Comment: @Zetys. Added an edit. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you want `Read` to read in a string that you will then pass to `Writeline`. In that case, `Read` has to return a value. Python strings are immutable, so you have to return the string you read to access it outside the function:

```
def Writeline(string):
    print(string)

def Read():
    return input()

name = Read()
Writeline(name)
```

**Edit**

Keep in mind that `input()` does different things in Pythons 2 and 3. In Python 3, it does what you appear to want. In Python 2 `raw_input()` is the function that reads in input. `input()` will attempt to evaluate anything you type as a line of Python code.

Answer (score 0):

First, go through the link that @Erica provided as a comment.

There's a few things going wrong here.

1. You haven't actually defined the variable "name" on a scope that is able to be used.
2. You are passing in name to function Read(), when you probably don't want to pass in any variable to begin with.
3. I think you want raw_input(), not input() (This only applies to python 2.x, as I did not see the 3.x tag)

What you need to do is assign the variable "name" to be the return of the Read() function.

Such as the following:

```
def WriteLine(s):
    print(s)

def Read():
    r = raw_input()
    return r

name = Read()
WriteLine(name)
```